# CakePHP 3 Sort by associated model with HasOne relationship

Tags: cakephp, pagination, cakephp-3.x

- Order HasOne Suborder
- Suborder BelongsTo Order

I need to sort Orders by a field in Suborders, but sorting by virtual fields appears to have been removed in Cake 3.x

In `OrdersTable.php`, I have

```
    $this->hasOne('Suborder', [
        'className' => 'Suborders',
        'foreignKey' => 'order_id',
        'strategy' => 'select',
        'conditions' => function ($exp, $query) {
            return $exp->add(['Suborder.id' => $query
                ->connection()
                ->newQuery()
                ->select(['SSO.id'])
                ->from(['SSO' => 'suborders'])
                ->where([
                    'Suborder.order_id = SSO.order_id',
                    'SSO.suborder_type_id in' => [1, 2, 3]
                ])
                ->order(['SSO.id' => 'DESC'])
                ->limit(1)]);
        }
    ]);
```

In `OrdersController.php`, I have

```
    $this->paginate = [
        'limit' => 20,
        'order' => ['id' => 'desc'],
        'sortWhitelist' => [
            'id',
            'title',
            'client_order',
            'substatus',
            'Workflows.order_status_id',
            'Clients.name',
            'ProductTypes.type',
            'Suborder.due_date',
            'Suborder.created',
        ],
    ];

    $orders = $this->paginate($collection);
```

In `index.ctp`, I have

```
    $this->Paginator->sort('Suborder.created', 'Order Placed'),
    $this->Paginator->sort('Suborder.due_date'),
```

and the error I'm getting is `Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Suborder.created' in 'order clause'`. How do I get Cake to include the Suborder in the initial query for sorting and pagination?

Edit:

```
    $collection = $this->Orders->find()
        ->contain([
            'Clients',
            'CurrentAssignment.Users',
            'Workflows.OrderStatuses.Category',
            'Workflows.OrderStatuses.Departments' => function ($q) use ($uID) {
                return $this->Departments->find()->matching('Users', function ($q) use ($uID) {
                    return $q->where(['Users.id' => $uID]);
                });
            },
            'ClientProducts.ProductTypes',
            'Reviews' => function ($q) {
                return $q->where(['review_type_id is not' => 6]);
            },
            'Reviews.ReviewTypes',
            'PublicNotes',
            'ActiveReview',
            'Suborder',
            'Suborder.SuborderTypes',
            'Suborders.SuborderTypes',
        ]);
```

and `$collection` is modified with 150 lines of wheres, orWheres, and joins based on a number of conditions.

Comment: While the cause is kind of obvious for people used to CakePHP, it may still depend on what exactly `$collection` is!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have configured the assocaition to use the `select` strategy, which will use a separate query to retrieve the data ([currently wrongly documented](https://github.com/cakephp/docs/pull/4469)), hence you cannot reference it in the main query used for pagination.

So you have to use the default `join` strategy instead if you want to sort on it.

See also

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Associations - Linking Tables Together > HasOne Associations](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html#hasone-associations)**